# Find object having the highest value in JSON in Postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Assume we have couple of objects in database with attribute `data` where attribute `data` consists: `{'gender' => {'male' => 40.0, 'female' => 30.0 => 'undefined' => 30.0}}`.

I would like to find only these objects, which have the `gender => male` value the highest.

PostgreSQL 9.5

Comment: `select * from your_table where 'male' = (select k from json_each_text(data->'gender') as j(k,v) order by v::numeric desc limit 1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly (example input/output would be useful):

```
WITH jsons(id, j) AS (
  VALUES
    (1, '{"gender": {"male": 40.0, "female": 30.0, "undefined": 30.0}}'::json),
    (2, '{"gender": {"male": 40.0, "female": 30.0, "undefined": 30.0}}'),
    (3, '{"gender": {"male": 0.0, "female": 30.0, "undefined": 30.0}}')
)
SELECT id, j
FROM jsons
WHERE (j->'gender'->>'male') :: float8 = (
  SELECT MAX((j->'gender'->>'male') :: float8)
  FROM jsons
)
;
┌────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ id │                               j                               │
├────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│  1 │ {"gender": {"male": 40.0, "female": 30.0, "undefined": 30.0}} │
│  2 │ {"gender": {"male": 40.0, "female": 30.0, "undefined": 30.0}} │
└────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(2 rows)
```